# Jquery adding new row datatables when sorting?

Tags: jquery, append, datatables

I am using server side to initilize Jquery DataTables

Like this:

**PHP**

```
  <?php 
       foreach ($customers as $customer)
        {

            echo'<tr>
                <td>'.$customer->name.'</td>
                <td>'.$customer->position.'</td>
                <td>'.$customer->office.'</td>
                <td>'.$customer->invoice.'</td>
                          <td class="text-right">
                          <a data-toggle="modal" href="'.base_url().'edit.html?name='.$customer->id.'" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success">Edit record</a>
                          <a data-toggle="modal" href="'.base_url().'edit.html?name='.$customer->id.'" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger">Delete record</a>
               </td>
            </tr>';
                    }

           ?>
```

The problem is after AJAX call i want upadte table i can easy do like this\

**Jquery**

```
$("#customers > tbody").append(" <tr><td>>Michael</td> <td>CEO</td> <td>Russia</td> <td>10</td> <td class='text-right'> <a data-toggle='modal' href='edit.html?name=1' data-target='#myModal' class='btn btn-success'>Edit record</a> <a data-toggle='modal' href='edit.html?name=1' data-target='#myModal' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete record</a> </td> ");
```

All is ok, data is appedn to table, the problem is when someone click on sorting, that append data disaper? Like it has never been in table?

Any idea how to update this code directly to Jquery DataTables function, but here I also have HTML code?

Or somebody can help me to make ajax call on that table, and when i finished update, maybe i can initilize table from ajax, only problem is that this is now ordinary JSON, i have button in rows?

Comment: After you append the rows, you may have to re- `$(selector).dataTable();`

Comment: Does not work, it get again row html and just that :(

Comment: [check this link out](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) for adding rows to the dataTable